# List of all JavaScript "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression" messages

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-error, ecma

Is there a comprehensive list of all possible JavaScript RegEx syntax violation error messages maintained anywhere?

```
try {
    new RegExp(pattern);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

For example, some possible error messages are:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\/: \ at end of pattern
```

Comment: What uses would such a list have?

Comment: This would be browser-specific. Probably you'd have to sift through the engine's source code.

Comment: use case is to know maximum length of an error reason to display in a regular expression validator modal window for sizing estimate

Comment: This really needs an update after the new ES 2018 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome V8 engine source code [regexp-parser.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/652c9522d3116faf9e8ba260dbc215462f380bd1/src/regexp/regexp-parser.cc)

```
"Regular expression too large"
"Unterminated group"
"Unmatched ')'"
"Nothing to repeat"
"Invalid group"
"Too many captures"
"\\ at end of pattern"
"Invalid property name"
"Invalid escape"
"Invalid decimal escape"
"Invalid unicode escape"
"Lone quantifier brackets"
"numbers out of order in {} quantifier"
"Incomplete quantifier"
"Invalid Unicode escape sequence"
"Invalid capture group name"
"Duplicate capture group name"
"Invalid named reference"
"Invalid named capture referenced"
"Invalid class escape"
"Invalid property name in character class"
```

21 distinct error messages, and the longest is 40 characters.

---

Mozilla SpiderMonkey engine source code [js.msg](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/b9d94b34d47daa34cfa76378e63db4ab978a70e7/js/src/js.msg).

```
"back reference out of range in regular expression"
"invalid range in character class"
"\\ at end of pattern"
"RegExp exec method should return object or null"
"invalid decimal escape in regular expression"
"invalid regexp group"
"invalid identity escape in regular expression"
"invalid unicode escape in regular expression"
"unterminated parenthetical"
"can't supply flags when constructing one RegExp from another"
"nothing to repeat"
"numbers out of order in {} quantifier."
"character class escape cannot be used in class range in regular expression"
"raw brace is not allowed in regular expression with unicode flag"
"raw bracket is not allowed in regular expression with unicode flag"
"too many parentheses in regular expression"
"Unicode codepoint must not be greater than 0x10FFFF in {0}"
"unmatched ) in regular expression"
"unterminated character class"
```

19 distinct error messages, and the longest is 74 characters.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on javascript engine.

For example for v8 engine browsers check [regex parser source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/regexp/regexp-parser.cc)

Search for this pattern `ReportError(CStrVector(` for all the errors.

And also [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/test/mjsunit/messages.js#L334) for the messages that are referenced as pointers in the parser.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing.